Ocelot route is not authenticating
I have this route in my Json file in gateway api
"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ChatController/send/specific",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 44396
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/ChatHubSpecificMessage",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
  "RouteIsAuthorized": true,
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
    "AllowedScopes": []
  }

The problem is that the API, where I send this request, can't identify the user, while authorizing works perfectly (if there is some problem with JWT token, 401 code is returned), but authenticating does not work at all (HttpContext.Claims is empty and ClaimsPrincipal's property IsAuthenticated returns false).
enter image description here
PS: in my gateway API, I also use authentication and authorization with JWT token and everything is fine, but in my other API, as I showed above, authentication doesn't work - only authorization does.
Also I tried to add in my Ocelot's json file, AddClaimsToRequest, like that
  "AddClaimsToRequest": {
    "UserId": "Claims[nameidentifier] > value[0] > |",
    "UserType": "Claims[role] > value[1] > |"
  } 

but in that case forbidden(status code 403) returns to me
